# Phone into boot-loop after flashing custom kernel; unable to mount /data and /sdcard from CWM

Tags: boot-loop, partitions

My Elephone P8000 was running Eragon 5.5 fine. Then I wanted to flash visi0nary's kernel (_1014), so I used the method described (fastboot flash ...), and when I rebooted the phone, it just kept into boot-looping.

I can still access CWM recovery, but I can't mount `/data` or `/sdcard`, so it's pretty bad.

I tried to flash the stock kernel but it didn't change anything. I think my partitions are messed up.

Here is my device's partition table :

[image]

When I try to mount `/data` with adb I get an invalid argument and when I check `/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/userdata` with e2fsck, it says that the superblock could not be read or does not describe an ext2 filesystem.

Comment: I believe you are the same person who posted the issue on XDA forum [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/elephone-p8000/help/brick-flashing-visi0narys-kernel-t3240759/post63650147).